# Administator can't access user record after migrating Openerp 7 to Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, upgrade

I'm trying to migrate from OpenERP 7 to Odoo 8 and I have succeeded in migrating most of the modules.

Except when I try to access any user's record (other than the administrator) from settings > users, I always get the message:

> The requested operation cannot be completed due to security
>   restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.
>
> (Document type: res.users, Operation: read)

What I tried to solve the problem is as follows:

- I thought the problem might be in the **'ir_rule'** model, so I deactivated all the rules but the result was the same.
- Some folks said it might be because the admin and the other users are not in the same company but I found that all the users are on the same company.

So, how could this happen? what could be the mistake that prevented the Administrator from being able to read the user's record but could access his own record?